# Unable to reindex product eav indexer

Tags: magento-2.0, indexing, import-products

Unable to reindex Product Eav Indexer.. I am getting that error message

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0-82-1-7.0000' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_idx` SELECT `cpe`.`entity_id`, `pdd`.`attribute_id`, `cs`.`store_id`, IF(pds.value_id > 0, pds.value, pdd.value) AS `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `pdd`
CROSS JOIN `store` AS `cs`  LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `pds` ON pds.entity_id = pdd.entity_id AND pds.attribute_id = pdd.attribute_id AND pds.store_id=cs.store_id
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `cpe` ON cpe.entity_id = pdd.entity_id
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_status` ON tad_status.entity_id = pdd.entity_id AND tad_status.attribute_id = 97 AND tad_status.store_id = 0
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_status` ON tas_status.entity_id = pdd.entity_id AND tas_status.attribute_id = 97 AND tas_status.store_id = cs.store_id WHERE (pdd.store_id=0) AND (cs.store_id!=0) AND (pdd.attribute_id IN('82')) AND (IF(pds.value_id > 0, pds.value, pdd.value) IS NOT NULL) AND (IF(IFNULL(tas_status.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_status.value, tad_status.value)=1)
```

Also when I Upload csv product file. Its was uploaded successfully. Its is displayed on admin. But when i go frontend, there is  message We can't find products matching the selection. I have done magento upgrade, deploy ,caching, re-indexing.